# Adding legend and changing scale on figure

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add a legend for the mean and median to my histogram. I am also trying to change the scale on the y-axis that is labeled count. It is currently showing the density scale. I want the density plot but the count scale. Alternatively, I would be fine with a second scale or the counts at the end of the histogram. I am just not sure how to go about it. Below is some data and the current code. Thank you in advance.

```
studyData=data.frame(X=rchisq(1:100000, df=3))
colnames(studyData) <- "hoursstudying"

mu <- data.frame(mean(studyData$hoursstudying))
colnames(mu) <- "Mean"
med <- data.frame(median(studyData$hoursstudying))
colnames(med) <- "Median"

p <- ggplot(studyData, aes(x = hoursstudying)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=(..density..)), binwidth = 1, colour = "black", fill = "lightblue") +
  geom_density(alpha=.2, fill="#FF6666") +
  geom_vline(data = mu, aes(xintercept = Mean),
             color = "red", linetype = "dashed", size = 1) +
  geom_vline(data = med, aes(xintercept = median(Median)),
             color = "purple", size = 1) + 
  labs(title = "Hours Spent Completing Course Work") +
  ylab("Count") +
  xlab("Hours Studying")
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
p
```

[image]

Comment: As an aside, your calculated mean and median are clearly wrong.  The mean of a chi-squared random variable on v df is v...

Answer (score 3):

You can access the count instead of density on the y axis much in the same way you reference the internal calculation of density using the "`..XXXX..`" notation.  In this case, use `..count..`.

You will need to change *both* `y` aesthetics for `geom_histogram()` and `geom_density()`:

```
ggplot(studyData, aes(x = hoursstudying)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=(..count..)), binwidth = 1, colour = "black", fill = "lightblue") +
  geom_density(aes(y=..count..), alpha=.2, fill="#FF6666") +
  # ... everything else is the same
```

[image]

*Note: also, I echo the comment from u/Limey.  The median and mean values in your original plot shared are clearly wrong... yet when I run the code I am getting the values looking correct.  Not sure what that's about, OP, but perhaps that's a different question.*

Answer (score 2):

Since @chemdork123 answered the question about the y-axis scale I won't say anything about it. To add the median/mean values to the legend you need to add them as aesthetics.

```
p <- ggplot(studyData, aes(x = hoursstudying)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=(..density..)), binwidth = 1, colour = "black", fill = "lightblue") +
  geom_density(alpha=.2, fill="#FF6666") +
  geom_vline(data = mu, aes(xintercept = Mean,
                            color = "red"),
             linetype = "dashed", size = 1) +
  geom_vline(data = med, aes(xintercept = Median,
                             color = "purple"),
             size = 1) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("purple", "red"),
                     labels = c("Median", "Mean")) +
  labs(title = "Hours Spent Completing Course Work") +
  ylab("Count") +
  xlab("Hours Studying") +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: You know, I totally missed the part of the OP question related to adding the legend.  Yes, this is the right idea.  I would also recommend for aesthetics to change the key glyphs of the legend for both to be a horizontal line by adding "`key_glyph="path"`" into each `geom_vline()` statement.  Since there are two `geom_vline()` calls, you need to add it to both of them or you will get double glyphs appearing.